# EF Core and Collection ordering by specified column: move up and down

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

What is a best way to implement ordering in collection?
Need to support operations like `move up` and `move down`.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you used OrderBy extension method?

Comment: Well, this question lacks all kinds of required details. For one, the relationship with EF isn't clear and you don't show any code that tells us where/how specifically you want to move items up and down and how you're (apparently) stuck in this process.

Comment: Here it is. Property Position used for `.OrderBy(o => o.Priority)`

Comment: I clearly understand how to move. But want to know is there any built-in solution in EF or best prctice for EF. I've did it manually but I don't want to make another one bicycle :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a console applciation which demonstrates how to move up and down elements of a list.

I hope it helps you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public enum MoveDirection
    {
        Up,
        Down
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> MyList = new List<string>
            {
                "Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"
            };

            DisplayList(MyList);
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Move(MyList, 1, MoveDirection.Down);
            DisplayList(MyList);
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Move(MyList, 2, MoveDirection.Up);
            DisplayList(MyList);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static void Move(List<string> list, int iIndexToMove, MoveDirection direction)
        {

            if (direction == MoveDirection.Up && iIndexToMove > 0)
            {
                var old = list[iIndexToMove - 1];
                list[iIndexToMove - 1] = list[iIndexToMove];
                list[iIndexToMove] = old;
            }
            else if(direction == MoveDirection.Down && iIndexToMove < list.Count() - 1)
            {
                var old = list[iIndexToMove + 1];
                list[iIndexToMove + 1] = list[iIndexToMove];
                list[iIndexToMove] = old;
            }
        }

        public static void DisplayList(List<string> list)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

    }
}
```